# App uses html_safe method, possible issues

Tags: web-application

For one who doesn't know, `.html_safe` is rails method, which outputs strings as part of html document.
The problem is that string is user inputed. What did I do to prevent some bad actions - regexp inserts after every `<` or `>`  invisible symbol, which breaks all tags, that could be part of html of document.
But still feel a bit unsure - does it protect page? Any other ways of use `.html_safe`, except tags, or symbol doesn't protects me enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [an article](https://makandracards.com/makandra/2579-everything-you-know-about-html_safe-is-wrong) explaining in details how `html_safe` actually works. In short, you should **not** call `.html_safe` in untrusted strings **or** in strings that contain other untrusted strings (e.g. `"trusted #{untrusted} trusted"`).

If you have a trusted string (not user inputted) that you need unescaped, you can call `html_safe` in it, and proceed appending other strings to it (or appending it to other `SafeBuffer`s). Every regular string appended to a `SafeBuffer` will be escaped, and thus can not cause XSS vulnerabilities. If you concatenate two `SafeBuffer`s, however, no escaping will occur.

Also according to the linked article, the rendering of every view starts with am empty `SafeBuffer`, so every string you append to it will be escaped by default.